# HPI image file view meta data in c#

Tags: c#, image, metadata

Anyone know of any c# libraries that allow loading and viewing HPI image meta data?

I need to view some meta data information from a HPI image file and i can't even load it into c# :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late, but the first 32 bytes are the meta data
from http://www.halley.cc/ed/linux/interop/hemera.html

file type signature { 89 48 50 49 0D 0A 1A 0A }

little-endian integer { 64 00 00 00 }; may be decimal 100 for version 1.0.0

little-endian integer e.g. { 20 00 00 00 }; offset into file for beginning of JPEG data

little-endian integer e.g. { E8 F3 00 00 }; length in bytes of JPEG data

little-endian integer e.g. { 08 F4 00 00 }; offset into file for beginning of PNG mask data

little-endian integer e.g. { 25 42 00 00 }; length in bytes of PNG data

little-endian integer { 00 00 00 00 }; may be reserved for future use

and here you can find how to convert hpi to transparent png: http://websitedesign-seo.co.uk/website-design-company/2011/03/22/hpi2png-linux-hemera-photo-image-converter/